# Php SMTP mail Issue

Tags: php, smtp

I got a project which I need to create a personal web site but I can not send e mail via contact form. Could you pls assist me what do I need to do in order to fix  it.

I have added class.phpmailer.php and class.smtp.php. Here is php code;

```
<? php

include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; //  or  587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
 $mail->Username = "behzatdeniz82@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "myseccretpassword"; //Don't reveal password with others
$mail->SetFrom("behzatdeniz82@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("behzatdeniz99@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
 {
 echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 }
 else
 {
 echo "Message has been sent";
 }
 ?>
```

After I change the php code as above, now I begin to receive this error. Can anyone help me how to fix ?

```
 SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" 
 - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? (1702478359) 
 SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: 
 Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `SetFrom` method is missing. There are multiple versions of PHPMailer available. [Download PHPMailer 5.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/) which contains a `setFrom` method:

```
  public function SetFrom($address, $name = '',$auto=1) {
```

Just Try.

Comment: Thanks Jenson.. It seems you are right. But now I have received below error message: "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Error mail could not be sent: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. "

Comment: @user2993130 Have you downloaded mentioned PHPMailer library & set all configuration values?

Comment: No Jenson. I am so new at PHP.. :(   How can I do this ?  Also I am working in localhost.

Comment: @user2993130 Have you downloaded http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/files/phpmailer%20for%20php5_6/ ?

Comment: I have just downloaded it and only copied class.phpmailer and class.smtp into my wamp/www directory. Do I need to copy another file into www directory ?

Comment: @user2993130 You've to copy entire folder & place your contact.html & mail1.php in the newly downloaded PHPmailer directory.

Comment: Received the same error. "SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host." Do I need to make any changes in below ? <? php

include 'class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.sitem.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = 'my@adress.com';
$mail->Password = 'topsecret';
$mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, 'My Name');
$mail->AddAddress('receiver@adress.com', 'Receiver Name');
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Subject = 'Mail Subject';
$mail->MsgHTML('Mail Content!');
if($mail->Send()) {
....

Comment: @user2993130 Chat discussion doesn't allow cuz of your low reputation. You can connect with me @ jenson555@gmail.com

Comment: @user2993130 Update with this code : http://pastebin.com/bUEvDdkt [Provide actual values for the variables in your code] Juz try I haven't tested this but.

Answer (score 0):

just a small bug, which may be the solution: a missing ' here, after My Name, $mail->SetFrom($mail->Username, 'My Name);

Comment: yes, I have amended but still receiving the same mistake.